# Why is my animation is not smooth when first playing?

Tags: java, animation, timer, jscrollpane

I have made an animation by changing the value of the horizontal scroll bar of a `JScrollPane`, something like the transition between the screens of android OS. In the first seconds (up to 10 seconds) of running, if i ask for animation, it is not smooth and has jumping; but after a while that I play with that (ask for animation), it gets completely smooth. Why that happens and more important how to solve that?

**I don't mean the first seconds of my animation is not smooth, I mean while I start my program the first times that I ask for animation that is not smooth but later, in the next times, that is smooth**.

```
    final JScrollBar br = mainContainerScrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar();
        ActionListener toTheRight = new ActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if (br.getValue() + 140 <= destinationScreenValue)
            {
                br.setValue(br.getValue() + 140);
            } else
            {
                br.setValue(destinationScreenValue);
                currentScreenName = destinationScreenName;
                timer.stop();
            }
        }
    };
        timer = new Timer(10, toTheRight);
        timer.setRepeats(true);
        timer.setCoalesce(true);
        timer.start();
```

Comment: With out any code example showing us what it is your doing, we'd be wasting each others time guessing at what could be wrong

Comment: sorry, i wrote my code, please notice what is written in bold

Comment: @trashgod no, not related...please read again

Comment: @syb0rg why?!!! please read what i wrote in bold

Comment: Because you didn't have any code posted at the time of my comment.

Comment: This is a common problem.  There's an old (OK, maybe months old) trick -- Run the animation once with it hidden, to get everything "limbered up".

Comment: @HotLicks seems interesting but how to run that hidden ?

Comment: @Soheil - That's up to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running at 100 Hz is going to saturate the EDT almost immediately, which will collide with normal JVM startup overhead. Some alternatives:

- Use the approach shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3256941/230513) to check your animation budget.
- Try [profiling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2064427/230513) at a lower rate to find the optimal value for your target platform(s).
- Specify an initial delay for the `Timer` that gets past the startup overhead.
- Start with a lower frame rate and ramp up the value, using a shorter delay, *after* things settle down.

Addendum: Here' are some examples that dynamically vary the animation rate:

- A [`Test`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11233735/230513) of `FloatSpring` that simulates [Hooke's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooke%27s_law).
- [`TestAnimatedWindow`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14796414/230513) that dynamically adjusts the bounds of a `Window`.

Comment: `Start with a lower frame rate and ramp up the value, using a shorter delay, after things settle down` do you suggest that even if the whole animation lasts 1 second?

Comment: Under the right circumstances, certainly; for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11233735/230513).

Comment: @soheil Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14789107/how-to-make-this-java-animation-smooth/14796414#14796414). It's an example of scalable animation, where the amount of change is determined by the amount of time that the animation has to play