# How can I make a smooth animation in java instead of a stuttering

Tags: java, swing

I'm making a game for practice and when I hit enter a knife pops up and I want it to look like its flying through air. Right now each time I click enter it skips about an inch and stops.

```
    im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0), "onEnter");

    am.put("onEnter", new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // Enter pressed
            throwKnife = true;
            if(move)
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                        knifeX += i;
                        repaint();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e1)
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                if(knifeX > 1200)
                {
                    throwKnife = false;
                    move = false;
                    knifeX = imageX+100;
                    knifeY = imageY+75;
                }
            }
            throwKnife = true;
        }
    });
```

This is paired with the following code in my paint component method

```
    if(throwKnife)
    {
        g.drawImage(knife, knifeX, knifeY, this);
        repaint();
        move = true;
    }
```

Comment: `Thread.sleep(10);` is no-go on the main-thread, you need to implement some kind of Timer, that will call your `move` function every 10 ms.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the use of the key bindings API and `repaint`, I'm guessing you're using Swing, in which case you're blocking the event dispatching thread with the `Thread.sleep`

See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for the reason why

Have a look at [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for a simple solution

I should also point out that the `ActionListener` will be called repeatedly while the key is held down.  A better solution would be to use a flag to indicate when the key is "active" and a "main loop" (like a Swing `Timer`) to update the state accordingly

Of course, this will require you to detect when the key is released, which can be achieved by binding the key again, but for release.  See [`KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(int, int, boolean)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/KeyStroke.html#getKeyStroke-int-int-boolean-) for more details

For example, maybe have a look at

- [smooth animation in java for fast moving objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27681998/smooth-animation-in-java-for-fast-moving-objects/27682530#27682530)
- [How to make this java animation smooth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14789107/how-to-make-this-java-animation-smooth/14796414#14796414)
- [How can I make a Java Swing animation smoother](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15511282/how-can-i-make-a-java-swing-animation-smoother/15511869#15511869)
- [How to make line animation smoother?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540534/how-to-make-line-animation-smoother/13547895#13547895)
- [Smooth out Java paint animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15329117/smooth-out-java-paint-animations/15329514#15329514)
- [How do I make smoother movement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43844824/how-do-i-make-smoother-movement/43845640#43845640)

Comment: Seriously? Why the downvote? `Thread.sleep` is the problem, a Swing `Timer` is a viable solution?  Oh, I didn't provide a copy and paste answer, instead I'm encouraging the OP to be pro-active and research the issue and solution themselves, bad me for wanting to make the developer more self relient and self suficent

Comment: `I'm encouraging the OP to be pro-active and research the issue and solution themselves` - totally agree. You have given the OP more help than he deserves considering the he has asked a dozen questions and not once taken the time to "accept" an answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Right now each time I click enter it skips about an inch and stops.

I believe that in the part you wrote `if(move){...}` you actually wanted `while(move){...}`.

With the `while` clause you can have it move until it satisfies certain condition (like knifeX > 1200).

So, your code should look like this:

```
while(move)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(10);
            knifeX += i;
            repaint();
        } catch (InterruptedException e1)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    if(knifeX > 1200)
    {
        throwKnife = false;
        move = false;
        knifeX = imageX+100;
        knifeY = imageY+75;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Generally, it won't work any better then the solution the OP has as the `Thread.sleep` will block the EDT, preventing it from updating the UI until the loop is completed